# How to use variables in os/exec in GO?

Tags: go

Just started to learn GO.
Need to add rule into iptables.
Thats how i read ip from client

```
  func get_client_ip(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  ip,_,_ := net.SplitHostPort(r.RemoteAddr)
   }
```

I need use "ip" variable here

```
cmd := exec.Command("iptables", "-I INPUT -s ip -j ACCEPT")
```

What is the right way to use variables in os/exec ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command arguments map one to one with function arguments to exec.Command. Do it like this:

```
cmd := exec.Command("iptables", "-I", "INPUT", "-s", ip, "-j", "ACCEPT")
```

The code in the question passes  "-I INPUT -s ip -j ACCEPT" as a single argument to the command. That's not what you want.